# did not able to display background image in codeigniter

Tags: html, css

I am trying to set the background image in CodeIgniter but I did not understand where I did my mistake. Can you please help me?

**CSS code:**

```
.main {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: auto;
    text-align: center;
    /*color: #fff;*/
    background-image: url(../img/main.jpg);
    background-position: center;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
}
```

**HTML code:**

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>css/creative_cook.css" type="text/css">

</head>
<body>
<div class="main">

------HTML Code----------- 
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Please show me my mistake.

Comment: You need a certain `height` to see the image, place some block elements  inside or text - `min-height:auto` do not exist - http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_min-height.asp.

Comment: thanx @ Luis now its working